# How to Inverse Where Clause in mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm querying my MySQL "consumer_details" table where the age is **>** 30 and purchase_count **>** **100**,  by the same time I need to exclude the people who age is equal ( = ) **50** and purchase_count  <  **100**

I'm running the following query right now :

**Base Query :**

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `consumer_details` 
    WHERE `age` > 30 AND `purchase_count ` > 100 
    ORDER BY `gender` DESC
```

**Extended Query :**

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `consumer_details` 
    WHERE `age` > 30 AND `purchase_count ` > 100  
         NOT IN (`age` = 50 AND `purchase_count ` < 100 ) 
    ORDER BY `gender` DESC
```

Comment: what about WHERE `age` > 30 AND `age` != 50 AND `purchase_count ` > 100?

Comment: Surely anyone with a purchase_count < 100 is already excluded by your test of `\`purchase_count\` > 100 `

Comment: I am also struggling to see why the first query which will not include `age` = 50 AND `purchase_count ` < 100 does not fulfill your requirement

Comment: BTW your first queries have a space in `purchase_count ` is that deliberate a typo or an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM consumer_details 
WHERE   (age > 30 AND purchase_count > 100)
AND NOT (age = 50 AND purchase_count < 100) 
ORDER BY gender DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to exclude all consumers who are exactly 50 years old you can use `and age != 50` in your where clause.

```sql
create table consumer_details (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    age int not null,
    purchase_count int not null,
    gender varchar(10) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
insert into consumer_details (age, purchase_count, gender) values(18, 99, 'female');
insert into consumer_details (age, purchase_count, gender) values(99, 101, 'male');
insert into consumer_details (age, purchase_count, gender) values(50, 101, 'female');
insert into consumer_details (age, purchase_count, gender) values(50, 99, 'male');
insert into consumer_details (age, purchase_count, gender) values(49, 99, 'female');
insert into consumer_details (age, purchase_count, gender) values(49, 101, 'male');
```

```sql
select * 
  from consumer_details
  where age > 30 
      and age <> 50
      and purchase_count > 100
  order by gender desc;
```

If you want to exlude all consumers who are exactly 50 years old **AND** have a purchase_count lower than 100 you can add a sub-query to exclude.

```sql
select * 
  from consumer_details
  where age > 30 and purchase_count > 100
    and id not in (
      select id from consumer_details where age = 50 and purchase_count < 100
    )
  order by gender desc;
```

Fiddle with with extended where clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4bc5f/1

Fiddle with sub-query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3701c2/4

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of this condition:

```
WHERE `age` > 30 AND `purchase_count ` > 100
```

is:

```
WHERE NOT (age > 30 AND `purchase_count ` > 100) OR
      age IS NULL OR `purchase_count ` IS NULL
```

It is very important to consider `NULL` values in comparison logic.

You can also express this as:

```
WHERE age <= 30 OR
      `purchase_count `<= 100 OR
      age IS NULL OR
      `purchase_count ` IS NULL
```